# Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

main screen code :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:day_event_viewer/services/firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TodayEventScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodayEventScreenState createState() => _TodayEventScreenState();
}

class _TodayEventScreenState extends State<TodayEventScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: getUserDatas(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return const Text('loading data');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].toString());
                },
              );
            }
            return const Text('somethng\'s wrong');
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

stream getUserDatas() code :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:day_event_viewer/screens/add_screen.dart';

Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUserDatas() async* {
  final uid = await getUid();
  yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('usersdatas')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('profile')
      .snapshots();
}
```

it is giving me "Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'" in my screen. what is this and how can I get the data in firestore. I'm new to firebase so anyone's help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to display instance not the actual value you want,you should try to display   return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].here the data you want to display.toString());

Comment: i can't type anything there where you said here the data you want to display. Help me I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: @Xone did you have any model class.

Comment: @Xone the data i mean to say is that for example return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].email.toString()); just a example.....

Comment: i don't have model class and I'm still stuck here..

Comment: @Xone what value you want to return as Text in your your listview? and also share your full error.

Comment: i changed the method of it. still i'm getting error. check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73067015/im-getting-a-blank-screen-instead-of-firestore-data

Comment: @Xone I have updated my answer there..please check

Comment: Mark if it solved your issue there..

Answer (score 2):

When you load data from Firestore, you get a `DocumentSnapshot` for each document. Since you're calling `toString()` on that here, you see the debug representation of the object in your UI:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index].toString());
},
```

What you probably want is to get one or more of the fields from the document's data, and display that. Say that your document contains a field called `message`, you can display that value with:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  var doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
  var data = doc.data() as Map;
  return Text(data['message']);
},
```

I recommend also having a look at the documentation on [showing realtime results from Firestore in Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) as it has a quite elaborate example.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my huge confusion.